# RPC server is unavailable using getmac

Tags: rpc

Trying to perform a getmac from ServerA to a remote ServerB (getmac /v /s ServerB) I receive this error: ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.

This is what I checked:

- RPC service is running
- file sharing enabled
- firewall is off on both servers
- telnet on port 135 is working fine
- IPv6 is enabled
- List item
- DNS and IP are correct

Do you have any other suggestion?

It seems that the communication is fine from the server I’m using to run getmac but the answer from the ServerB is not going back to ServerA

Any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks

I started RPC services
Check firewall